# How to configure the path while installing new plugin in linux?

Tags: linux, packages, rpm

Whenever I need to install something on Xentos, I found rpm or tar balls.

I want to know what is difference between two.

Also if I need to install something for php but I have installed on different folder, how can i give that php path while using configure command in newly downloaded tar.gz package ?

Comment: Never heard of Xentos, maybe you mean Centos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An RPM is an archive with a lot of special things in it. It's for installing already built software and sometimes source (usually marked as an SRPM, for source RPM). Besides the files itself, it may also have preinstall scripts, postinstall scripts, and also preremove and postremove scripts if you ever want to remove the software.  It keeps things tidy by keeping some install info in the RPM db. You need to be root to install, not only because the files (almost always) get installed in places that usually only root has access to, but you need to be root to change the RPM db.

A `tarball` in general is just an archive. A collection of files and directories. What you have is a source tarball, one that you need to configure and run for your specific install. Once you extract the tarball (`tar -xzvf /path/to/something.tar.gz` will extract it). Most software uses something called `autoconf` which generates a script called `configure` which can configure your source for building. It does some checks (do you have a compiler? are your libraries new enough?) and can take some command line flags. Use `configure --help` to see what these flags are. Usually the only flag you need is `--prefix=/path/to/somewhere` to say where you want to install.  Once you run configure you can run `make && make install` to install it. Or, `sudo make install` if  you are using root only locations.

Anything past the `prefix=...` flag is very dependent on your source, and what pre-exists on your computer. I don't know your package, nor do I know how php connects to it. Does `configure --help` list any flags for php path? Sometimes you just put the interpreter into your PATH e.g. PATH=/path/to/php/bin:$PATH. The `configure` script then (may) find php and query it (things that use perl work this way). You may need some post build configuration after. Be prepared to experiment.

Since you said you have things in non-standard locations, your choice may just be the source tarball. RPMs are prebuilt, and tend to have few options for configuration.

Answer (score 2):

RPM is  a pre-made package - you can use either a graphical  tool or `rpm` (CLI) to 
install it.

Tarballs are source code. You can usually get away with just running

`./configure && make && make install`

If you need to change the install path of a package, do something like this:

`./configure --prefix=/this/is/where/everything/goes 
  && make && sudo make install`

(or use `su -c`: I'm a Zenwalker and can't really say which is preferred on RH based distros)

which will end up with a directory tree like:

```
/this/is/.../goes/bin
/this/is/.../goes/doc
/this/is/.../goes/share
```

If this is not what you want in regards to chaging the install path, feel free to be more specific, as `./configure` has the following path options:

> Fine tuning of the installation
>   directories:
>
> --bindir=DIR           user executables [EPREFIX/bin]
>
> --sbindir=DIR           system admin executables [EPREFIX/sbin]
>
> --libexecdir=DIR        program executables [EPREFIX/libexec]
>
> --sysconfdir=DIR        read-only single-machine data [PREFIX/etc]
>
> --sharedstatedir=DIR    modifiable architecture-independent data [PREFIX/com]
>
> --localstatedir=DIR     modifiable single-machine data [PREFIX/var]
>
> --libdir=DIR            object code libraries [EPREFIX/lib]
>
> --includedir=DIR        C header files [PREFIX/include]
>
> --oldincludedir=DIR     C header files for non-gccv[/usr/include]
>
> --datarootdir=DIR       read-only arch.-independent data root [PREFIX/share]
>
> --datadir=DIR           read-only architecture-independent data [DATAROOTDIR]
>
> --infodir=DIR           info documentation [DATAROOTDIR/info]
>
> --localedir=DIR         locale-dependent data [DATAROOTDIR/locale]
>
> --mandir=DIR            man documentation [DATAROOTDIR/man]
>
> --docdir=DIR            documentation root [DATAROOTDIR/doc/bullet]
>
> --htmldir=DIR           html documentation [DOCDIR]
>
> --dvidir=DIR            dvi documentation [DOCDIR]
>
> --pdfdir=DIR            pdf documentation [DOCDIR]
>
> --psdir=DIR             ps documentation [DOCDIR]